# How can I change field values of posts before displaying

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have `wordpress` project with `woocommerce`. What I'm trying to achieve is to change values before displaying them on the view page.

For example depending on `session/cookie` I want to change the language of post title and content

Using the hooks `the_title, the_content` I was able to achieve it. 
The problem is when I try to do the same for `the_excerpt` hook, it's just never called.

Relevant code from `functions.php` :

```
add_filter('the_title', 'custom_lang_title');

function custom_lang_title($title){
    if($otherlang){
        return get_field('lang_title');
    }else{
        return $title;
    }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'custom_lang_desc');

function custom_lang_desc($content){
    if($otherlang){
        return get_field('lang_content');
    }else{
        return $content;
    }
}


//The code below does not work

add_filter('the_excerpt', 'custom_lang_excerpt');

function custom_lang_excerpt($desc){
    if($otherlang){
        return get_field('lang_excerpt');
    }else{
        return $desc;
    }
}
```

I'm completely new to wordpress, so if don't really know what other info can be helpful. I can provide more info on request.

Comment: Are you certain the theme uses `the_excerpt()`? Also, you're not defining `$otherlang`. Is this the actual code?

Comment: this is only the relevant part of the `functions.php`, `$otherlang` is just a boolean. I'm sure that db uses `post_excerpt`, i'm not so sure about it using the `the_excerpt` hook

Comment: Is there another way I can modify post_excerpt?

Comment: No, not without a hook. But whether or not the hook is available, or which hook to use, depends on the template. What does the template that you’re trying to translate look like?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean by template. Is it template of view page ? If so, i'm not trying to translate it, Only the 3 values, title, content and excerpt from `wp_posts` table

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that themes/plugins do not change the behaviour of native WP hooks, we use filters and actions to add/change functionality. Am I correct ? I thought the_excerpt was native WP hook.

Comment: It is, but `$post->post_excerpt` is the raw value. You can only filter it if it's output with the `the_excerpt()` function or `get_the_excerpt()`, which internally apply the `the_excerpt` hook. So you cannot filter the value on output unless those functions are used. If your theme uses `echo $post->post_excerpt`, you cannot filter it.

Comment: ah ha, got it now. Thank you for the explanation. I will check the source when I get home. I think I can work it out from here.

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie I managed to solve the issue with your explanation. Using woocommerce's get_short_description hook. If you assemble your comments into answer, I will gladly accept it. Thank you once more.